# NestedScrollView scrolls page too much

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to implement something like an Instagram profile page with the `NestedScrollView` widget. So I combine this with a `TabBar` widget. I have two tabs. Detail and comments. Then I have other widgets on top of the `TabBar`. Everything works as expected so far. But the problem starts when I scroll. Even though there is nothing inside my tabs, `NestedScrollView` scrolls too much, and my TabBar widget comes to the top of the screen. In Instagram, if you have no photos, you can not scroll the page. But in my application, I can scroll. And this is the behavior I want to prevent. How can I do this? I also share my codes and screenshots of the unwanted behavior.

**This is the page**

[image: This is the page]

**This is the over scroll even though there is nothing to show inside the tab bar**

[image: This is the over scroll even though there is nothing to show inside the tab bar]

These are the codes:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Home Page"),
      ),
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, isScrolled) {
            return [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  child: const Placeholder(
                    fallbackHeight: 300,
                    fallbackWidth: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.amberAccent,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SliverPersistentHeader(
                pinned: true,
                delegate: StickyTabBarDelegate(
                  child: const TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.black,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: "Detail"),
                      Tab(text: "Comments"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ];
          },
          body: const TabBarView(
            children: [
              DetailTab(),
              CommentsTab(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailTab extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

class CommentsTab extends StatelessWidget {
  const CommentsTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

class StickyTabBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final TabBar child;

  StickyTabBarDelegate({required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: child,
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => child.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  double get minExtent => child.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: if you are talking about `body`, yes it  will cover full body.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh is there a way to limit the scroll extent when there are no contents in it? Because showing the whole empty page to the user is so bad.

Comment: Another option can be replacing nested scrollView with something else

Comment: I tried to use only CustomScrollView without NestedScrollView but the result is still the same.